# Edit .cfg files with PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0, config, computer-science

I have a .cfg file that looks something like this

```
Block 1  
   attr_1    = 0
   attr_2    = "a"
END

Block 2
   attr_1    = 0
   attr_2    = "b"
END

Block 3
   attr_1    = 0
   attr_2    = "a"

END
```

How can I use a powershell script to change the value of attr_1 to 1 in all blocks with attr_2 = "a"?

I.e. The result should look like the following:

```
Block 1  
   attr_1    = 1    #attr_1 is changed
   attr_2    = "a"
END

Block 2
   attr_1    = 0
   attr_2    = "b"
END

Block 3
   attr_1    = 1    #att_1 is changed 
   attr_2    = "a"

END
```

I know that for XML files powershell can make changes to the attribute of each node, but how can you accomplish this with .cfg files? I am using Powershell V2.0. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about .CFG files, and neither does PowerShell, but based on your example, you can probably do the job using regular expressions.

```
# Read the file in blocks delimited by lines starting with 'END'
$blocks = Get-Content temp.cfg -Delimiter "`nEND"

# Process those blocks matching a criteria
$blocks = $blocks | ForEach-Object { 
    if ($_ -match '\battr_2\s*=\s*"a"') { 
        # replace specified attribute
        $_ = $_ -replace '\b(attr_1\s*=)\s*0\b', '$1 1'
    }
    $_
}

# Write the blocks to another file...
$blocks | set-content temp2.cfg -NoNewline
```

I've written the regular expressions so that they should only change parts that closely match your example.

P.S.  I haven't double checked this works on PowerShell 2, but I think so.   Also, depending on what's reading these files, you may need to specify `-Encoding Ascii` (or something) on Set-Content.